# DCOS serverServer responded with an HTTP 'www-authenticate' field of 'oauthjwt', DCOS only supports 'Basic'

Tags: dcos

I just create new DCOS cluster and trying to run dcos CLI commands. For any commands I got the following error:

dcos package list

> Server responded with an HTTP 'www-authenticate' field of 'oauthjwt', DCOS only supports 'Basic'

I check dcos.toml and it contains correct parameters: dcos_url contains http url, email, token

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you opt out (https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/opt-out/)?

Comment: Looks like we do not specify this parameter anywhere, so it should be true by default

Comment: ok, then, next question is: did you run `dcos auth login`?

Comment: no, I do not have auth command at all

Comment: If you are on DC/OS 1.7 and have no `auth` subcommand you likely have an outdated CLI version, see https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/usage/cli/update/

Comment: yes, it helps. Now I asked for the token. I get token from link provided, but it is rejected. Looks like DC/OS 1.7 change authentication dramatically ...

Comment: Please join http://chat.dcos.io and let's take it from there …